# Search and replace whole HTML strings with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble searching an d replacing an entire string of HTML.

My example in this fiddle is me trying to replace an entire div tag with all of its classes and markup.

HTML:

```
<ul class="slides">
      <li><div class="flex-caption"><strong>Climb to the Top of Your Potential</strong>&nbsp;</div></li>
      <li><div class="flex-caption"><strong>Reach for the Clouds with Simple Solutions</strong>&nbsp;</div></li>
      <li><div class="flex-caption"><strong>Obtain the Courage to Suceed as a Leader, Team, & Company</strong>&nbsp;</div></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
// This works perfect to search & replace text strings, but not for searching HTML:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function makeLink () {
jQuery(".flex-caption").html(function(i, str) {
return str.replace("Climb to the Top of Your Potential", "<div class='caption-align'>Climb to the Top of <a href='http://google.com'>Your Potential</a></div>");
});
}makeLink();
});

// Issue #1: This is my failed attempt to search & replace a large portion of the string:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function changeString () {
jQuery(".flex-caption").html(function(i, str) {
return str.replace("<div class='flex-caption'><strong>Reach for the Clouds with Simple Solutions</strong></div>", "<div class='flex-caption'><strong><div class='caption-align caption-right'>REPLACED TEXT! Reach for the Clouds with Simple Solutions</div></strong>&nbsp;</div>");
});
}changeString();
});

// Issue #2: I don't know why the character "&" is break this, so I tried \u0026 & both CDATA with no avail:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function changeString2 () {
jQuery(".flex-caption").html(function(i, str) {
return str.replace("<strong>Obtain the Courage to Suceed as a Leader, Team, \u0026 Company", "<i>Obtain the Courage to Suceed as a Leader, Team, \u0026 Company");
});
}changeString2();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqkNE/

As you can see, there are two little issues-- one with an ampersand that's causing me problems too.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/jeVjn/

As stated above, `&` needs to be encoded and for the first issue, you can replace only the strong part as the rest doesn't change

EDIT:

```
// Issue #1: This is my failed attempt to search & replace a large portion of the string:

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  function changeString() {
    jQuery(".flex-caption").parent().html(function (i, str) {
      return str.replace(
        '<div class="flex-caption"><strong>Reach for the Clouds with Simple Solutions</strong>&nbsp;</div>', 
        "<div class='flex-caption flex-align'><strong><div class='caption-align caption-right'>REPLACED TEXT! Reach for the Clouds with Simple Solutions</div></strong>&nbsp;</div>"
      );
    });
  }

  changeString();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeVjn/1/

Note the `parent()`, simple quote and `&nbsp;` This was not working because `.flex-caption` html is `<strong>...` not `<div class=".flex-caption">...`

Comment: I need to add a class after the initial div's .flex-caption class. Are you saying that's not possible?

Comment: a class to what? In fact I don't see the use case here

Comment: Where it says `<li><div class="flex-caption"><strong>Reach` I would like it to add a class: `<li><div class="flex-caption flex-align"><strong>Reach` but only on the 2nd list item (hence the word Reach being included in this example) --- is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `&` needs to be encoded as `&amp;`

So the html should be:

```
      <li><div class="flex-caption"><strong>Obtain the Courage to Suceed as a Leader, Team, &amp; Company</strong>&nbsp;</div></li>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  function changeString2 () {
    jQuery(".flex-caption").html(function(i, str) {
      return str.replace("<strong>Obtain the Courage to Suceed as a Leader, Team, &amp; Company", "<i>Obtain the Courage to Suceed as a Leader, Team, &amp; Company");
    });
  }
  changeString2();
});
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Issue #2 solved-- I'll keep trying to work on Issue #1.